# How to create week start data and week end date column using power bi for graph visualization?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

We have continuous date series data and we have to visualize week start date and week end date wise on chart, how to implement it.

My table is

[image]

Comment: Can we interpret each row of the table as a participant of a survey? Is it a correct understanding that the first row represents a participant who joined the survey from August 1 to August 7, and his screen usage was 36 hours in total across 3 different days?

Comment: Sure will update you give sometime. What i did here is based on start date i create column i have created weekend Saturdays and its duration count. Will update actual description of table. Thanks for comment. Table altered due to understanding.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to seeing the description. And also, it would help visitors of this question for better understanding if you could make your question more focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can able to calculate In the following ways

**Syntax :** `WEEKDAY(DATE,WEEK_STARTDATE_OPTION)`

1. Sunday=1 through Saturday=7
2. Monday=1 through Sunday=7
3. Monday=0 through Sunday=6

`Week start date = MedianScreenUsagePerDay[startDate] - WEEKDAY(MedianScreenUsagePerDay[startDate],1)`

`Week end date = MedianScreenUsagePerDay[startDate] - WEEKDAY(MedianScreenUsagePerDay[startDate],1) + 7`

After created new Week ending Saturdays column

[image]

Week ending Saturdays, we are displaying through ribbon chart

[image]